# Laravel 5.2 relationships returning empty array

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models and need to pull both and filter the results based on some conditions

Mobile: id, name, make ...

Offer: id, modelid, retailerid...

my Models are set up like this:

```
// Mobile
public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App/Offer','modelid','id');
}


// Offer
public function mobile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Mobile','modelid');
}
```

when I run

```
 $offers = App\Mobile::with(['offer'=>function($q){
     $q->orderBy('phonecost','asc')->first();
 }])->orderBy('Popularity','desc')->paginate(10);
```

I get an empty array in the offer relationship

Comment: Start by debugging your laravel query, see what the actual generated SQL is so you can figure out where it went wrong. https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

Comment: it is just ignoring the relationship all together and not querying the other table at all

Comment: Also, I don't think it's correct to use `first()` in the `with()` callback as you did it. `first()` executes a query, but you are dealing with eager loading. You can constrain the loading like this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads. Not to mention you're getting a single result by using `first()`.

Comment: Hmm I don't think that's the issue even if I drop the function and just have with('offer') it still ignores the relationship and only queries the mobiles table

Comment: Your foreign key is `modelid` in the `offer` function but in the `mobile` function, it looks like it's `mobileid`.

Comment: ah well spotted sadly that was just a typo in my post is modelid on all of my laravel Models and funcitons :(

Comment: I think the issue is with my fieldnames if I select a few fields on the relationship it works if however I ask it for all the fields it does not